# Change activity orientation from Custom View

Tags: android

In my application, I'm starting a fragment via xml layout. i.e.

```
 <fragment class="com.fragment.MyFragment" .../>
```

This fragment in one of this adapter renders a custom view.

In this view there is a button, which when clicked, should change orientation of the activity (progmatically).

Now, since I do not have any context in this CustomView.java, how can I change the activity's orientation?

Comment: A `View` has a reference to the `Context`(the `Activity`) through `getContext()`.

Comment: @Luksprog can you please explain with example. Thank You

Comment: Your "CustomView.java" is a View right? so it has a getContext() method. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `Context` from your view, you can call `getContext()` and do whatever you want with it.
To change the orientation, you can check if the `Context` is an `Activity` and call `setRequestedOrientation(int)`.